# Are resized or moved partitions in any way worse than unmanipulated partitions?

Tags: partitioning

In comparing a resized or moved partition to unmanipulated partitions (as in created and used partitions that have never been resized or moved), are the unmanipulated in any way worse given that both are properly aligned?

I'm *not* asking which is safest way to handle because I know that resizing or moving partitions might harm them so that data is lost. What I'm asking is if there's any relevant difference of resized or moved partition and unmanipulated partitions such as in performance or security given that both are properly aligned. That is, is resizing or moving partition in any way advised against if it's *excluded* that you might lose data as you do it and that you might mess up alignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, assuming there are no errors during the move or resize operation, there is no difference between the original partition and the modified one. It's just copying of digital data from one place to another, there is no degradation of data like you would get with an analog videotape or something.

It is possible that other things that refer to the locations of partitions, such as boot loaders, might be affected by the change if they are not properly updated.